# Stop footer movement on android keyboard pop-up in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, footer, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am having a hybrid app and whenever I click on any DOM input the keyboard comes and it takes my footer also along with at its top. But I need that the footer is stuck always at the bottom. What is the best way to do it ? Also am using the below jquery but it doesn't works flawlessly. Also in this jquery, I need to skip some input boxes whose classname not equals to **item** . How to add this exception ? Also is there any other nice way out to accomplish this task ?

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {     

                        /* bind events */

                        $(document)  
                        .on('focus', 'input[type=text]")', function() { 
                            $('.footer').css('position', 'absolute');
                            $('.footer').css('bottom', ''); 
                        })

                        .on('blur', 'input[type=text]', function() { 
                            $('.footer').css('position', 'fixed');  
                            $('.footer').css('bottom', '0');
                        });



                    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? @sqlchild

Comment: @Hemant.Gupta : the mentioned jquery works